# jQuery FAQ details show/hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a jQuery beginner.
I created a FAQ-like page in which when i click the question, its details will show up and the rest of the answers will be hidden. Please check my code and give your suggestion. Also, give any alternate code, if any, with explanation.

[Code in codepen](https://codepen.io/birdie90/details/qXjOYo/)
index.php

```js
$("div").children("p").hide();
    $(document).ready(function () {
    
        $("h1").click(function () {
            $("div").children("p").hide();
            $(this).next("p").show();
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>FAQ</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="faq">
                <h1>1. Question 1</h1>
                <p>Details1</p>
                <h1>2. Question 2</h1>
                <p>Details 2</p>
                <h1>3. Question 3</h1>
                <p>Details 3</p>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: better move this question to code review stack

Comment: why dont you use bootstrap accordion. look [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion)

Comment: $("div").children("p").hide(); add this line inside $(document).ready()

Comment: While it works here, `.next("p")` probably doesn't do what you think it does.  It's very rare you'd use `.next(selector)` rather than just `.next()` or `.nextAll(select).first()`

Comment: Give your div wrapper a class (which you already have) and use that, rather than `$("div").children` because as soon as you add any other divs to the page it will also affect them:  `$("div.faq").children("p").hide()` .   Same applies to the `h1` - use a div with a styled class and trigger on that class.

Answer (score 1):

You use `slideToggle()` and `$("div").children("p").hide();` on DOM ready:

```js
$("h1").on('click', function() {
  $(this).next("p").slideToggle('slow');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div").children("p").hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>FAQ</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="faq">
    <h1>1. Question 1</h1>
    <p>Details1</p>
    <h1>2. Question 2</h1>
    <p>Details 2</p>
    <h1>3. Question 3</h1>
    <p>Details 3</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Read this line in question _when i click the question, its details will show up and the rest of the answers will be hidden_

Comment: This would give you and expand/collapse, not an according as desired.  (personally I'd prefer expand/collapse, but it's not what was requested).

Comment: Ok, My miss. In that case, hide all when you click on `h1`

Comment: Your code is now the same as OPs :)  (except the startup hide all and your event should be in doc startup)

Comment: _give any alternate code_, I could shown slideToggle which is expand/collapse

Answer (score 1):

I would give some classes to the elements.
The answers will certainly be more than just one `<p>`.
So I would wrap them in a `<div>` with a class to target it.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".answer").hide();
  
  $(".question").click(function () {
    $(".answer").hide();
    $(this).next(".answer").show();
  });
});
```

```css
.someStyle{
  color:blue;
  font-family:arial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="faq">
  <h1 class="question">1. Question 1</h1>
  <div class="answer">
    <p>Details 1</p>
    <ol>
      <li> Some other elements!!!</li>
      <li> Cool.</li>
  </div>
  <h1 class="question">2. Question 2</h1>
  <div class="answer">
    <p>Details 2</p>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/sports">
  </div>
  <h1 class="question">3. Question 3</h1>
  <div class="answer">
    <p>Details 3</p>
    Okay... <span class="someStyle">That is an answer.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.
add onclick in all h1 tags

```
<h1 onclick="fun(this)">1. Question 1</h1>
```

Then use this in your script

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $("div").children("p").hide();
});
function fun(el){
$(el).next().show();//show the details of current question
 $(el).siblings("h").hide();//hide all other questions
}
```